# Linq Join on Multiple Properties

Tags: vb.net, linq

Are the below two queries functionally the same?
The first one doesn't return any data, but the second works fine with same exact input.
What's wrong in my first query?

```
Dim LTest2 As IEnumerable = From e1 As QNCEntity In Shape.Entities _
                        Join e2 As QNCEntity In Shape.Entities _
                        On New With { _
                                     .X = CDbl(e1.EntObj.X2), _
                                     .Y = CDbl(e1.EntObj.Y2) _
                                    } _
                        Equals New With { _
                                           .X = CDbl(e2.EntObj.X1), _
                                           .Y = CDbl(e2.EntObj.Y1) _
                                        }

Dim LTest3 As IEnumerable = From e1 As QNCEntity In Shape.Entities _
                               Join e2 As QNCEntity In Shape.Entities _
                               On CDbl(e1.EntObj.X2) Equals CDbl(e2.EntObj.X1) _
                               And CDbl(e1.EntObj.Y2) Equals CDbl(e2.EntObj.Y1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of an anonymous type with ***no key properties*** is `Equal` only to itself.

See: [MSDN article on Anonymous Types, Header - Key Properties, Equality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)

To make the first query work the same as the second, you need to change your first code sample to mark the X and Y properties as key properties:

```
Dim LTest2 As IEnumerable = From e1 As QNCEntity In Shape.Entities _
                        Join e2 As QNCEntity In Shape.Entities _
                        On New With { _
                                      Key .X = CDbl(e1.EntObj.X2), _
                                      Key .Y = CDbl(e1.EntObj.Y2) _
                                    } _
                        Equals New With { _
                                          Key .X = CDbl(e2.EntObj.X1), _
                                          Key .Y = CDbl(e2.EntObj.Y1) _
                                        }
```

The key fields will be compared by value for an equality test instead of comparing the references to the two anonymous types.

Comment: Wish I could give this more than +1, this issue (not having the "key") has been driving me crazy all day

Answer (score 0):

Is `Width` a class? Yes? In this case the first query will compare the objects by reference while the second one will compare the actual values. (... and the references will - of course - never match because you always create a new instance.)

Comment: "New With" is a VB.NET idiom for creating anonymous objects

Comment: Good to know (I am C# developer) ... I assumed a typo. In this case I am completly wrong.